# Laravel, how to filter records from a custom model method before paginating it?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `products` and `variants`. They have one to many relationship, product can have multiple variants. The table 'products' doesn't have a price column, that column is within the `variants` table. **The product's price is represented by the lowest price of its variants in the dashboard**.

In the dashboard, I need to make a function that sorts the product's price from lowest to highest and paginates it. Due to the nature of Eloquent builder and my intentional database design, it's not that simple. Because I have to use model methods in order to access the lowest price of the variants like this:

```
protected function price(): Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(get: function(){
        return $this->variants()->get()->min('price');
    }); 
}
```

I've tried a couple of things like using `sortBy` but that's only for collection so I can't paginate it, even if I can, that would be a huge memory loss if the query is big enough because of the nature of collection.

**Summary**

How can I sort the data by a custom model method (price) in my builder before paginating it?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$products = Product::select('products.*')
    ->selectSub(function ($query) {
        $query->from('variants')
            ->selectRaw('MIN(price)')
            ->whereColumn('product_id', 'products.id');
    }, 'lowest_price')
    ->orderBy('lowest_price', 'asc')
    ->paginate(10);
```